# how to remove duplicated video frame in ffmpeg ? but have to do not all video but some seconds section.

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

i have MTS(avchd) 2hrs video , but  this video have duplicated frames range of  between 00:00:00;00 ~ 00:00:00;20 , some time 3frames , sometime 2frames , sometime 9frames and so on ...
so i have to do remove duplicated frame for this section . 
even if out of this section duplicated frame then have to keep . should not  be removed